# Integrating federated OAuth2 login into an API service?

Tags: api, oauth, federated-identity

We're building a public API and clients using this API will need to authenticate, and we proposed to expose an `OAuth2 API` for this purpose.

However, we also have a need for authentication to be federated, so we see clients talking `OAuth 2` with our API, and our API talking `OAuth1/2` or `SAML2` to the identity provider in the background.

The full flow being:

1. Client talks OAuth2 to our API.
2. At the start of this flow, our API redirects the client to a "Choose Your Federated Provider" HTML page.
3. On choosing a provider, our API talks OAauth1/2 with the provider, passing any redirects back to the client, so the user can provide login details.
4. Our API exchanges the access code for a access token and refresh token (API keeps these private, and uses them even if the client is off-line).
5. Our API generates an access code and passes this to the client.
6. Client exchanges the access code for access token.

The provider supplied access token/refresh token is use by the API in the background, for example to keep a Google calendar up to date, and not passed to the client.

I've not found any examples of this being done with an API. So, what is the established model for providing federated authentication for an API service?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Nice first question!

Answer (score 0):

Check out some of the info that Ping Identity provides on their [OAuth Essentials page](https://www.pingidentity.com/resource-center/oauth-essentials.cfm). Specifically, there is a White Paper entitled, "A Standards-based Mobile App IdM Architecture White Paper" (free w/Registration) that you should look at that talks about how you would use SAML + OAuth to secure Native Mobile Apps that require Federation. [Note: I do work for Ping]. It lays out the info flows and token exchanges that need to happen to solve this use case as well as other OAuth related cases.

HTH - Ian

Comment: Ian, that's almost what I'm looking at, however the "Native Application with Federation" flow described in the paper assumes the application controls the choice of federated IDP. What we're going for is we (the SP) control the federated IDP selection, because it is not the native app that is registered with the IDP, it is our SP API.

Comment: I haven't looked super-close at the doc. However, I believe if you ask the end user to enter their email address (or their domain) into the native client to kick off the process, your SP API can determine the appropriate IDP to redirect to for the user to properly authenticate. BTW - PingFederate can handle the SAML and AS in all this OOTB. :-)